# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when creating NEW project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Unlike the other article on this topic, I know that it is not related to my code, because I get the error when attempting to create a NEW project in Visual Studio.

Does anyone know what this means? NOTE: This error first occurred after a system cleanup (I uninstalled any Microsoft product 2010 and earlier that had a newer version installed (e.g. old versions of Visual Studio, etc). Sadly, I didn't keep track of these, so I have no idea what the cause of the error it. (Lesson learned!)

I have re-installed Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 but am still getting the error.

Comment: Does this happen regardless of the project type?

Comment: Good point. I just tested it. It only happens when creating a Web Forms project.

(On a side note, maybe it's the Universe telling me it's time to switch to MVC)

Comment: The accepted answer (at the bottom of the page) at http://forums.asp.net/t/1945953.aspx?+Object+reference+not+set+when+creating+new+project+from+Web+Application+template might help as it seems to solve the same problem for VS2013.